# Why am i crashing here?

Tags: ios4, addressbook, abaddressbook

The firstname, lastname and email address work great! as soon as I get to address, im crashing.

```
            NSString *firstName =       (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
            NSString *lastName  =       (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
            NSString *emailAddress  =   (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty);
            NSString *address   =       (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
            NSString *city      =       (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonAddressCityKey);
            NSString *state     =       (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
            NSString *zip       =       (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonAddressZIPKey);
```

Comment: Can you give more context around it? I expect the problem to be somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Address is MultiValue Property (`(a multivalue property of type kABMultiDictionaryPropertyType`)  you can not access it like this directly using `ABRecordRef` object.

You first need to get that multivalue property and then using this you can access the street,city and other address properties.